# Error using in() with an array of tuples using Julia

Tags: julia

I have 2 arrays of tuples and I have a loop asking if one element is in the other. 
At each step I ask if the tuple contained in the coord array is in the Y array. The loop works fine except for one element which I cant explain why. Here is what I have :

```
Y[55:65] # This is the array I want to check at each step if my state is in or not.
```

> 11-element Array{Any,1}:  (2.0, 1.0)  (3.0, 1.0)  (4.0, 1.0)  (5.0,
>   1.0)  (6.0, 1.0)  (7.0, 1.0)  (8.0, 1.0)  (9.0, 1.0)  (10.0, 1.0)  (11.0, 1.0)  (12.0, 1.0)

```
coord[i-1]  # this is one element of coord that is in Y
```

> 0-dimensional Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}: (6.0, 1.0)

```
coord[i] # this is an other element of coord that is in Y
```

> 0-dimensional Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}: (7.0, 1.0)

But then when I test when they are in Y:

```
in(coord[i],Y[55:65]) # testing if coord[i] is in Y
```

> false

```
in(coord[i-1],Y[55:65]) # testing if coord[i-1] is in Y
```

> true

I dont understand: they are both represented in the same way in Y, they have the same type, why do I get from using in() that one is in and not the other?

I use Julia version 0.6.3.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Most likely `Y[55:65]` contains `(7.0, 1.0)` wrapped in an 0-dimensional array and `(6.0, 1.0)` is not wrapped. They get printed in the same way so it is hard to distinguish them using visual inspection only. But this might be the case as `Y[55:65]` is a `Vector{Any}` so it seems that it contains mixed types. Can you post the result of `typeof.(Y[55:65])`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. `typeof.(Y[55:65])` gives : 

``11-element Array{DataType,1}:
 Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}
 Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}
 Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}
 Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}
 Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}
 Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}
 Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}
 Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}
 Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}
 Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}
 Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}``

Comment: I cant find what is the difference between these 2.

Comment: It seems that the type is the same. So what does `Y[60] == coord[i]` comparison return? If it is `false` then what `Y[60][][1] == coord[i][][1]` and `Y[60][][2] == coord[i][][2]` return? If any of these two return `false` then actually entries of the tuples are not equal (which can happe if you are working with `Float64` due to rounding).

Comment: Thank you for your help, yes I realised the values indeed were not totally equal, but differed by the machine precision. which is weird because I did something like 7/100*100, I did not expect that to happen! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you get `coord` and `Y`? If you get them by calculations rather than direct assignments, they may not be exactly equal even if they are displayed so. For example:

```
julia> p1 = fill((6.0, 1.0))
0-dimensional Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}:
(6.0, 1.0)

julia> p2 = fill((7.0 + 3eps(), 1.0))
0-dimensional Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}:
(7.000000000000001, 1.0)

julia> Y = [p1, p2]
2-element Array{Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0},1}:
 (6.0, 1.0)
 (7.0, 1.0) # NOTE that it get truncated in display but the content did not changed!

julia> x = fill((6.0, 1.0))
0-dimensional Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}:
(6.0, 1.0)

julia> x in Y
true

julia> x = fill((7.0, 1.0))
0-dimensional Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},0}:
(7.0, 1.0)

julia> x in Y
false
```

If this is the case, you can either round them before comparing or write the `in` function mannually using `isapprox` (or the `≈` operator, typed in Julia by `\approx` + Tab)

Comment: yes that was the problem! but I did not think about that before as the way I computed was 7/100*100. Good to know for the future! Thank you very much. isapprox sounds more appropriate, I will check for the precision.