# How can I use logical condition for this array?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I need to compare 2 elements of a array as following

```
V=([-180.0 -117.0; -67.5 -111.0], [-117.0 -36.0; -111.0 -244.5])
```

when I use the following condition

```
if (V[1][:,2] != V[2][:,1])
```

It gets true. But `V[1][:,2] = [-117.0;-111.0]` and `V[2][:,1] = [-117.0;-111.0]` so They

are equal and the condition should be false.

would you please help me that why it replies like this?

thanks

Comment: `V[1][:,2] != V[2][:,1]` is `false`. Why do you think it is true?

Comment: would you please say what is the problem?   I have 2 Points V[1][:,2]=[-117.0;-111.0]  ,  V[2][:,1] = [-117.0;-111.0]. They are same. so if (V[1][:,2] != V[2][:,1]) should be false. but it is true despite they are same.

Comment: I found what is the problem. it was because of the decimals of  these points. I used round( V[1][:,2],5). so my problem was solved. if (round(V[1][:,2],5) != round(V[2][:,1],5))

Comment: Sounds like similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366825/error-using-in-with-an-array-of-tuples-using-julia/51382884 . If the error is from floating number arithmetic, `≉` is probably another option, typed by `\napprox` then press tab. see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.isapprox